# How do you get input type of file to auto post back on selection in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, file, input

I have an ASP.NET Webform and inside the form I have an input type of file.  What I would like to happen is for the form to post immediately after the user chooses a file.

I have a server side function I would like to be called, let's say UploadedFile()

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using jQuery you can do it like this: http://www.bitsandpix.com/entry/jquery-file-upload-auto-submit-using-jqueryparentsexp/

**Edit:**
That of course only addresses the submit part. You should probably be using a [`FileUpload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) control instead of an `input type=file` in order to wire up the correct server side event.